# StoreKit's SKErrorPaymentCancelled still charge user's itunes account

Tags: ios, itunes, storekit

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKitTypes/Reference/reference.html, SKErrorPaymentCancelled means that user cancelled a payment request.  However, in our production app, we are getting a failed transaction with error code = SKErrorPaymentCancelled but there was a charge to the user's account (user later sent it a receipt as a proof).  Looking at the error, it said "cannot connect to itunes store".  Are we doing something wrong?  Why is the user getting charged even though the error is SKErrorPaymentCancelled?

Note that we also listen to transaction when the app starts to capture all missed transaction that comes our way.

Comment: Same issue here, appeared recently. @Herman did this start happening recently for you guys too?

Comment: I would recommend opening a developer support request. We have done that but of course they are not taking it seriously...